Angular V18 ERROR ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
Error from Angular Console
ERROR ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
    at _CartService.getCartFormLocalStorage (/Users/jan/Projekts/PflanzenApp/src/app/services/cart.service.ts:64:21)
    at _CartService (/Users/jan/Projekts/PflanzenApp/src/app/services/cart.service.ts:12:28)
    at Object.CartService_Factory (/Users/jan/Projekts/PflanzenApp/src/app/services/cart.service.ts:66:3)
    at eval (/Users/jan/Projekts/PflanzenApp/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:3233:47)
    at runInInjectorProfilerContext (/Users/jan/Projekts/PflanzenApp/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:871:9)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (/Users/jan/Projekts/PflanzenApp/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:3232:21)
    at R3Injector.get (/Users/jan/Projekts/PflanzenApp/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:3095:33)
    at ChainedInjector.get (/Users/jan/Projekts/PflanzenApp/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:16599:36)
    at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (/Users/jan/Projekts/PflanzenApp/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:5746:39)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (/Users/jan/Projekts/PflanzenApp/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:5794:12)

Error Browser:
core.mjs:6619 ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': ']' is not a valid attribute name.
    at EmulatedEncapsulationDomRenderer2.setAttribute (http://localhost:4200/@fs/Users/jan/Projekts/PflanzenApp/.angular/cache/18.0.2/vite/deps/chunk-3JBJB2WG.js?v=e3cfc332:2873:10)
    at setUpAttributes (http://localhost:4200/@fs/Users/jan/Projekts/PflanzenApp/.angular/cache/18.0.2/vite/deps/chunk-5K2TKP3A.js?v=e3cfc332:2703:18)
    at setupStaticAttributes (http://localhost:4200/@fs/Users/jan/Projekts/PflanzenApp/.angular/cache/18.0.2/vite/deps/chunk-5K2TKP3A.js?v=e3cfc332:7957:5)
    at Module.ɵɵelementStart (http://localhost:4200/@fs/Users/jan/Projekts/PflanzenApp/.angular/cache/18.0.2/vite/deps/chunk-5K2TKP3A.js?v=e3cfc332:15639:3)
    at ShoppingCartTitleComponent_Template (http://localhost:4200/main.js:843:9)
    at executeTemplate (http://localhost:4200/@fs/Users/jan/Projekts/PflanzenApp/.angular/cache/18.0.2/vite/deps/chunk-5K2TKP3A.js?v=e3cfc332:8146:5)
    at renderView (http://localhost:4200/@fs/Users/jan/Projekts/PflanzenApp/.angular/cache/18.0.2/vite/deps/chunk-5K2TKP3A.js?v=e3cfc332:8932:7)
    at renderComponent (http://localhost:4200/@fs/Users/jan/Projekts/PflanzenApp/.angular/cache/18.0.2/vite/deps/chunk-5K2TKP3A.js?v=e3cfc332:8914:3)
    at renderChildComponents (http://localhost:4200/@fs/Users/jan/Projekts/PflanzenApp/.angular/cache/18.0.2/vite/deps/chunk-5K2TKP3A.js?v=e3cfc332:8961:5)
    at renderView (http://localhost:4200/@fs/Users/jan/Projekts/PflanzenApp/.angular/cache/18.0.2/vite/deps/chunk-5K2TKP3A.js?v=e3cfc332:8946:7)

Here is the code of my CartService:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Cart } from '../classes/cart';
import { Observable,BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { Plant } from '../classes/plants';
import { CartItem } from '../classes/cart-item';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CartService {
  private cart:Cart = this.getCartFormLocalStorage();
  private cartSubject: BehaviorSubject<Cart> = new BehaviorSubject(this.cart);
  constructor() { }

  addToCart(plant: Plant): void {
    let cartItem = this.cart.items.find(item => item.plant.id === plant.id);
    
    if (cartItem) 
        return;

    this.cart.items.push(new CartItem(plant));
    this.setCartToLocalStorage();

}

removeFromCart(plantId: string): void {
  const plantIdNumber = Number(plantId);
  this.cart.items = this.cart.items.filter(item => item.plant.id !== plantIdNumber);
  this.setCartToLocalStorage();
}

changeQuantity(plantId: string, quantity: number): void {
  const plantIdNumber = Number(plantId);
  let cartItem = this.cart.items.find(item => item.plant.id === plantIdNumber);

  if (!cartItem) 
    return;

  cartItem.quantity = quantity;
  cartItem.price = quantity* cartItem.plant.price;
  this.setCartToLocalStorage();
  }

  clearCart(){
    this.cart = new Cart();
    this.setCartToLocalStorage();
  }

  getCartObservable():Observable<Cart>{
    return this.cartSubject.asObservable();

  }

  private setCartToLocalStorage():void{
    this.cart.totalPrice = this.cart.items.reduce((prevSum, currenItem) => prevSum + currenItem.price, 0) 
    this.cart.totalCount = this.cart.items.reduce((prevSum, currenItem) => prevSum + currenItem.quantity, 0) 
    const cartJson = JSON.stringify(this.cart);
    localStorage.setItem('Cart', cartJson);
    this.cartSubject.next(this.cart);
  }

  private getCartFormLocalStorage():Cart{
   const cartJson = localStorage.getItem('Cart');
   return cartJson? JSON.parse(cartJson):new Cart(); 
  }

}

Everything except the components that use the service work fine and as expected. I also tried using localstorage-polyfill but it did nothing. Any ideas why this happens or is there just a new way to do it in Angular Version 18?

we'll need the template for the 2nd error.

Here is the projects Github Link:
https://github.com/jamakr4/PflanzenApp

You have an extra square bracket in https://github.com/jamakr4/PflanzenApp/blob/main/src/app/shopping-cart-title/shopping-cart-title.component.html

Thank you so much! I would have never seen that!
